# Slowing the Move of an Object in a For Loop Java

Tags: java, for-loop, motion

I am currently working on a project that moves a circle from a space to space when button is pressed. I designed as following: When the button is pressed, it increments the coordinates of circle, in a for loop from 0 to 10.

The problem is, the motion I wanted with for loop doesn't show up on the screen but it only shows the object on the first and the last coordinates, so it doesn't move one by one.

Any suggestion would be appreciated,

Kutay Demireren

Comment: You need a timer or a sleep between moving pixels

Comment: In addition, you need to repaint the screen after every iteration.

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't make thread work on my code tho, although I repainted after every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a frame draw length that the human eye can see in order for motion to work properly.  The can be achieved in many ways, but the easiest is with a thread.sleep at the end of each for loop iteration for however long you want the different pictures to be visible for.

Comment: I added Thread.sleep(100) at the end of for iteration. It just wait for 100 miliseconds, then show at last coordinate

Comment: Yeah it is a fraction of my school project, I am not allowed to. Sorry for that. Still thanks lot